# How to handle Security Error due to the cross origin

Tags: javascript

Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.bhjk.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://c.betrad.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Heres' my code:

```
 getBody: function(slot) {

    //Here I'm checking if div id is null to avoid type errors later
    if(document.getElementById(this.getDomId(slot)) != null){
    var iframe = document.getElementById(this.getDomId(slot)).getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    console.log("iframe is:");
    console.log(iframe);
    }
    else{
    return false;
    }
      console.log("now checking for same origin policy");
console.log(iframe.contentDocument.body);
    if(iframe) return iframe.contentDocument.body;
        return false;
    },
```

To be more specific the below statement is giving me problems. Wahts the best way to handle the above error wrt this code?

```
if(iframe) return iframe.contentDocument.body;
```

Comment: Are you doing a same-origin policy check and want to know how to catch the error, or do you want to know how to get around it?

Comment: i want to know how to get rid of the above error. "Uncaught SecurityError"

Comment: That didn’t actually answer my question.

Comment: I'm not doing anycheck. my site cannot access and iframe within itself which is from some other domain. I want a correct way to handle it with respect to the code above

Comment: Not do it? It’s impossible, for security reasons.

Comment: what are u trying to convey exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps with a try-catch block:

```
try{
   return iframe.contentDocument.body;
}catch(exception){
  console.log(exception);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: in what respect? what did the console say?

Comment: Actually, I asked "what does the console show?", not "what does it not show?" and if the console isn't showing the error then its been caught which is apparently what you wanted

Comment: if its caught should I not see what I've console.logged in the catch?

Comment: The question is not clear, if you're trying to read cross domain content from an iframe, the answer is simple, you can't. If you're trying to determine if the iframe is loading cross domain content then the above should work

Comment: yeah you are right I can't read a cross domain content but I just tried using the try catch & hard refreshed & it still shows me security error in the console. Is there any other way to hadnle this? My code is breaking because of this.

Comment: I just tested it with `var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];` it worked fine